# How to convert string that doesn't have date format into date in informatica

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

i have a date like this `$$date='20230614'`
what i want is to convert this string to date like this `'2023/06/14'`

i tried to convert it on expression transformation using TO_Date function

```
TO_DATE($$date,'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

i also tried this

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE($$date,'YYYYDDMM'),'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

but both didn't work

Comment: Can you explain what "Didn't work" means? Did it error (what's the error message?); did it cause something to fail further in your mapping workflow (if so, what and how)?

Comment: it gave me this error
Transformation Parse Fatal Error

Comment: I'm guessing that you have data that cannot be parsed as a date in that format. Have a look at the error logs and it should be obvious (you may need to turn up the logging level to verbose data)

Comment: The latter is the correct way to do it. If there is an error, you need to check it. And share the details if you can't figure this out. Perhaps the variable value is not what you exepect?

Comment: It seems to me you reversed days and month for the `TO_DATE` function. I believe the complete expression `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE($$date,'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYY/MM/DD')` will give the result you expect.
_Transformation Parse Fatal Error_ is probably caused by Informatica trying to convert `14` to a month.

Comment: 1. are you passing correct value of `$$date` through param file ? if yes, then, make sure its showing up in session log correctly. 2. use correct data function  `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE($$date,'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYY/MM/DD')` 3. check if data type of above field is VARCHAR